# Usar Jquery Autocomplete em propriedades Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui

Tenho meu Model da seguinte maneira

```
public class Album {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int ArtistaId {get;set;}
}
public class Artista {
   public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

E na minha View, utilizo:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ArtistaId, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Problema:

Eu queria utilizar um `AutoComplete`, para ele buscar e setar o `ArtistaId`.
Porém, como ele é um "`Id`", e ao preencher esse `TextBox`, ele informa no `ValidationMessage` que o campo aceita apenas dados numéricos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Autocomplete está correto. O comportamento seria certo se você estivesse preenchendo o Id na mão, o que não faz sentido dentro deste contexto.

Coloque no seu Model um campo de texto não mapeado em banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
public class Album 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ArtistaId {get;set;}

    [NotMapped]
    public String NomeArtista { get; set; }

    public virtual Artista Artista { get; set; }
}
```

A View vai ficar da seguinte forma:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ArtistaId)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NomeArtista, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Coloque o Autocomplete em `NomeArtista`, colocando no evento `success` o preenchimento de `ArtistaId`.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, bom, depois de muito e muito ler, eu removi os repository e service =), e como nesse caso eu não tenho ViewModel(removi também) eu não sabia como resolver. Aproveitando, feliz ano novo =)

Comment: @Rod ViewModel não precisa remover. Feliz Ano Novo!

Comment: eu só vi utilidade nas ViewModel, em Alguns models, em muitos era só "duplicação" de código...usava AutoMapper, Agora para os Grids retorno um DTO que é "quase a mesma coisa"